# Set the width of table headings TH with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, telerik

I'm using telerik mvc grid with custom row template. So since I'm done with my row template I have problem with th`s width. I can't set width properly so I can't make a simple document ready function to set width of each th.

```
function SetWidth(){
    var ths = $('th');
    var element = ths[0];
    element.width(100);
}
```

Then I'll manually set 0 = 100, 1 = 110, 2 = 300 px and so on.

But when I try to add width of 'element' , it gives me error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'width' of object #<HTMLTableCellElement> is not a function
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using a standard DOM element.  You can change the width like this

```
function SetWidth(){
    var ths = $('th');
    var element = ths[0];
    element.style.width = 100;
}
```

or

```
var ths = $('th');
var element = ths.eq(0); //<-- instead of ths[0]
element.width(100);
```

Answer (score 1):

width() is not a valid javascript method of a standard DOM element which is the type of element you passed the th through to when you used `$("th")[0]`. It is a method of jQuery though.

You'll want to do this instead:

```
function SetWidth(){
    var widths = [100, 110, 300]
    for(var i=0; i<widths.length; i++){
        $('th')[i].style.width = widths[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: This one works, but i want to give different width of my TH`s.

For example
<th>Name</th> - 200px
<th>Name2</th> - 100px

Comment: Let me know if this works. I'm not exaclty sure what you are asking for? do you want to set a manual value for each th? or do you want each one to be 100 less than the last?

Comment: even if you want to use the other as your solution, make sure you look at this solution. it will use far less code and be quicker to edit than the current solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the css method instead:

```
element.css('width', '100');
```

Answer (score 0):

You cast the jQuery element back into a standard DOM element, and there's no `width` method on  a standard DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function SetWidth(){
    var ths = $('th');
    var element = ths[0]; // this gets a raw dom object
    element.style.width = 100; // therefor you should use style property
}
```

alternatively if you want to select first `th` element you can use jQuery `eq()` method:

```
    var ths = $('th:eq(0)').css('width', '100')
```